# background shape with smoothness css

Tags: css, background-color, css-shapes

how to create this shape in background. I tried using radial-gradient but still, the smoothness of round is not there. I also tried clip-path but it is cutting my other images on this page. I want this shape as my background colour. Is there any way?

I used
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 50% -249%, #117FC8, 90%, white 55%). But in this the round shape has little square.I want smooth curve.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack over flow please add a minimum reproducible example

Comment: try `background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 50% -249%, #117FC8 90%, white 92%)`

Comment: Thanks. I found my mistake. I used white 90.1%. Your answer gave me this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used `::before` to create that shape

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #00f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: -150px
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans but the image I shared is a full width page and I want to create this shape as a background image. I tried your solution but it will overwrite my content of this page.

Comment: Pls share your code with snippet. [FFI](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score -1):

You could use SVG shape instead of CSS shape. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)